# Constant of integration question

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone explain why the constant of integration is ln A in the following example.

$\int (1/x) dx = \int (1/y) dy$

$ln (x) + ln(A) = ln (y)$

Thank you

Comment: It makes no difference whether you call it $A$ or $\ln A$. It is just some constant. Any real number $B$ can be written as $\ln e^{B}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range of logarithmic function is all real number, so any real constant can be represented by it. In this example since both the results are in ln so it becomes easier to consider the constant as lnA.

we can also write lny-lnx=c

$ln\frac{y}{x}=c$ or $\frac{y}{x}=e^c$ (say A) and this y=Ax again